# Sorting Upper and Lower Case Letters by not changing its original Position

Tags: java

Input: `String [] str = {"B","h","g","H","G","b"};`

Without changing its first order , ex in input String "h" should be at first place and H will be at second place. 
Output: `String [] st = {"B","b","h","H","g","G"};`

```
public void stringSelection(String[] str,String[] st, String temp) {
    try {
        int k=0;
        for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++) {
            for(int j=1;j<str.length;j++) {
                if(i==1 && j==1) {
                    j++;
                    st[k]=str[i];
                    st[k+1]=str[j];
                    k=k+2;
                }
                else if(str[i].equalsIgnoreCase(str[j])) 

                {
                    /*temp=str[i+1];
                    str[i+1]=str[j];
                    str[j]=temp;
                    i++;*/

                    st[k]=str[i];
                    st[k+1]=str[j];
                    k=k+2;
                }

            }

        }
        for( int i=0;i<str.length;i++) {
            System.out.println("Values are:"+ st[i]);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}




public static void main(String[] args) {

    StringSelection ss = new StringSelection();
    String [] str = {"B","h","g","H","G","b"};
    int len = str.length;
    String [] st  = new String[len+3];
    String temp = "";
    ss.stringSelection(str,st,temp);

}
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: i want to change its order and get an output

Comment: That's not a question. What have you tried so far? What are you stuck on?

Comment: You need to do a  _case-insensitive._ sort using a _stable_ sort algorithm.  Bubble sort and insertion sort are examples of stable sort algorithms.

Comment: i have tried but my condition is to don't change the element position in that array. for Ex: if "h" is at 2 nd position and same H is at  next to h

Answer (score 1):

This will work and i have tested this -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String [] str = {"B","h","g","H","G","b"};
    ArrayList list[] = new ArrayList[26];
    for(int i=0; i<str.length; i++){
        int c  = str[i].toLowerCase().charAt(0) - 'a';
        if(list[c] == null){
            list[c] = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
        list[c].add(str[i]);
    }
    for(List<String> newList: list){
        if(newList != null){
            for(String x : newList){
                System.out.print(x + " ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

refer this [ideone](https://ideone.com/duvLm3)

Comment: Hey Thanks for this code and it worked .
Can you explain this (int c  = str[i].toLowerCase().charAt(0) - 'a';) piece of code

Comment: Hi wasim, if we think in ASCII 'a'-'a'=0, 'b'-'a'=1, 'c'-'a'=2........'z'-'a'=25 so i created 26 location which points to Arraylist i.e  ArrayList list[] = new ArrayList[26];
and add these character in that location itself. please debug this in IDE like intellij/eclipse.